# Show value based on condition

Tags: excel, excel-formula

To note down hours spended on various projects I need to display the project's name based on the entered project-id.

Example: when entering "**G.2**" in the highlighted cell I need "**Internet Support**" to appear in the **hour-list**.

I tried hardcoded IF-cases but it would be fancy to have this dynamic.

**Second Question**: How to sum up all hours in [E] and [K] related to the project?

[image: Project lists[![][1]]

---

[image]

Comment: Construct a small **VLOOKUP()** table and use it to retrieve the names.

Comment: Check [VLOOKUP function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/vlookup-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1). I think it may help, but you would need 2 columns: in first column you would input `G.2` and second column with this formula would show `Internet Support`

Comment: The question is not clear. When you enter "G.2" in one cell, you want "Internet Support" to appear where? The column names are not in English so I can't fully follow. Would a banal vlookup not work?

Comment: VLOOKUP works great! Ty. I am wondering if it is (simply) possible to sum up all hours related to a project, lets say, SUM [D] based on [E] and show in [E/K]

Comment: That shouls be in another question, but check [SUMIFS function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/sumifs-function-c9e748f5-7ea7-455d-9406-611cebce642b). It would allow you to sum a list of values, but only if those values in other columns meet the requirements you specify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may helps you:

**Formula for Vlookup:**

```
=IFERROR(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(E8,$A$2:$B$4,2,FALSE),VLOOKUP(E8,$G$2:$H$4,2,FALSE)),"Project not Exist")
```

**Formula for Sumif:**

```
=IFERROR(IFERROR(SUMIF(G2:G3,E8,I2:I3),SUMIF(A2:A4,E8,E2:E4)),"Project not Exist")
```

**Results:**
[image]